# Create AD user with python ldap3 not working correctly

Tags: python, ldap3

Here's my code:

'''

```
def create_ad_user(samaccountname, email, ou, nome='Test'):

print(samaccountname, email, ou)

server = Server('ldap://<my ldap server>', get_info=ALL, use_ssl=True)
conn = Connection(server, user='<my admin user>', password='<my admin 
password>',auto_bind=True)

password = 'Password123!'

# Crea l'utente
user_dn = f"CN={nome},{ou}"
attributes = {
    "objectClass": ["top", "person", "organizationalPerson", "user"],
    "sAMAccountName": samaccountname,
    "givenName": 'Test',
    "sn": 'Test',
    "mail": email,
    "description": 'Test creazione utenti con ldap3',
    "userPrincipalName": f"{samaccountname}@ssn.local",
    "unicodePwd": f'"{password}"'.encode("utf-16-le"),
    "userAccountControl": 512,  # Abilita l'account
}

success = conn.add(user_dn, attributes=attributes)
if not success:
    print(f"Errore nella creazione dell'utente: {conn.result}")
    return

# Modifica l'attributo pwdLastSet per forzare il cambio della password al prossimo accesso
conn.modify(user_dn, {"pwdLastSet": [(MODIFY_REPLACE, [0])]})

print(f"Utente {samaccountname} creato con successo in {ou}.")
```

'''

If i remove 'unicodePwd' and 'userAccountControl' everything works fine while if I add them the following exception is generated (output of conn.result):

{'result': 53, 'description': 'unwillingToPerform',
'dn': '', 'message': '0000001F: SvcErr: DSID-031A12E8, problem 5003 (WILL_NOT_PERFORM)
, data 0\n\x00', 'referrals': None, 'type': 'addResponse'}

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I tried to make it do the step by step actions first creating the user and then doing the conn.modify() first of the password and then of the enable but the modify of the password fails with same error...

Comment: I fixed it momentarily with an alternative method: I use subprocess to launch the powershell script with args where everything works.

Answer (score 0):

`userAccountControl` and `unicodePwd` are refused by AD when you're adding a new user. To overcome this, you need to:

1. Add the user account without those attributes. It will be locked/disabled after success.
2. Unlock the account:

   `conn.extend.microsoft.unlock_account(user=user_dn)`
3. Set password:

   `conn.extend.microsoft.modify_password(user=user_dn, new_password=password, old_password=None)`
4. Set userAccountControl and pwdLastSet:

   `conn.modify(user_dn, changes={"userAccountControl": (MODIFY_REPLACE, [512]), "pwdLastSet": [(MODIFY_REPLACE, [0])]})`